# Updating iOS app, in Xcode, name already in use error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When trying to update my iOS app, I get "App record creation failed due to request containing an attribute already in use. The App Name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a claim."

Like yeah, it exists, cause it's literally mine.

What's wrong? Do they mean bundle, SKU or the actual name (which defaults to runner)?

Comment: If you're correctly updating an existing app, there should be no place to enter an app name. What does "which defaults to runner" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to submit a new app instead of updating an existing app. Your update should be using the same bundle id otherwise it will be treated as a new app.